# Linking problems: Qt5.5 32bit VS2013

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013, qt5.5

I have been searching for an answer to this but no luck as yet.

Using Qt5.5 32bit, VS2013 on Win8 64bit

My .pro file contains this:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include"
LIBS += -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib" -ladvapi32
```

I have checked both folders and WinUser.h is in the Include and User32.lib is present in the Lib.

I have the following two functions in my code:

```
void suppressAnimations()
{
    ANIMATIONINFO m_original_settings;
    m_original_settings.cbSize = sizeof(m_original_settings);
    if (::SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETANIMATION, sizeof(m_original_settings), &m_original_settings, 0)) {
        ANIMATIONINFO no_animation = { sizeof(no_animation), 0 };
        ::SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETANIMATION, sizeof(no_animation), &no_animation, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
    }
}
```

AND

```
int BackgroundTaskManager::changeMonitorState(bool turnOn)
{
    int lparam = 2;
    if(turnOn) {
        lparam = -1;
        BackgroundTaskManager::MonitorIsSleeping = false;
    } else {
        lparam = 2;
        BackgroundTaskManager::MonitorIsSleeping = true;
    }
    return SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM)lparam);
}
```

I use this exact same code with Qt 5.3.2 32bit VS2010 on Windows 7 64bit and it compiles with no problems.  In my current configuration, I get linking errors on the ::SystemParametersInfo and the SendMessage parts of the functions and a bunch of warnings on the  headers.

**Warnings**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include\sal_supp.h:57: warning: C4005: '__useHeader' : macro redefinition
```

**Linking Errors**

```
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__SystemParametersInfoW@16 referenced in function "void __cdecl suppressAnimations(void)" (?suppressAnimations@@YAXXZ)
backgroundtaskmanager.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__SendMessageW@16 referenced in function "private: int __thiscall BackgroundTaskManager::changeMonitorState(bool)" (?changeMonitorState@BackgroundTaskManager@@AAEH_N@Z)
```

Another bit of information, I tried this also using Qt5.5 32bit VS2013 on Win7 64bit and also received the errors as above.  Yet another bit of information, in Qt Creator, I can press F2 over either of the symbols above and it takes me to the correct header.

Could someone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 1):

I knew it was something simple:

```
LIBS += -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib" -ladvapi32 -luser32
```

I did not link the user32.lib.